# Why is event.preventDefault() not working when making a POST request?

Tags: javascript, forms, post, dom-events, fetch-api

So, I am just trying to submit a form which makes a POST request to json-server and then displays that into a page. I don't want the page to refresh everytime I submit the form, so I added `event.preventDefault()` in the first line of the submit event. The POST request is successful, all the data from the form gets posted into my json-server, but for some reason, the page always refreshes when I submit.

Here's the block of code in question:

```
function monsterSubmit() {
    const monsterForm = document.getElementById("monster-form");
    monsterForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const monsterObj = {
            name: event.target[0].value,
            age: event.target[1].value,
            description: event.target[2].value
        }

        fetch("http://localhost:3000/monsters", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Accept: "application/json" 
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(monsterObj)
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(monster => console.log(monster))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

    })
}
```

I know the problem lies with the POST request somehow because when I comment it out, add `console.log("form submitted")`, and submit the form, the page does not refresh and I see the message posted to the console, but when I put it back in, the page refreshes on submit. Any clue what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Here is the JS file in its entirety:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    getMonsters();
    monsterSubmit();
})

function getMonsters() {
    const monsterContainer = document.getElementById("monster-container");
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/monsters?_limit=50")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(monsters => {
            monsters.forEach(monster => {
                const monsterName = document.createElement("h2");
                const monsterAge = document.createElement("h4");
                const monsterBio = document.createElement("p");
                const monsterInfo = document.createElement("div");

                monsterName.textContent = monster.name;
                monsterAge.textContent = `Age: ${monster.age}`;
                monsterBio.textContent = `Bio: ${monster.description}`;

                monsterInfo.append(monsterName, monsterAge, monsterBio);

                monsterContainer.appendChild(monsterInfo);
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
}

function monsterSubmit() {
    const monsterForm = document.getElementById("monster-form");
    monsterForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const monsterObj = {
            name: event.target[0].value,
            age: event.target[1].value,
            description: event.target[2].value
        }

        fetch("http://localhost:3000/monsters", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Accept: "application/json" 
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(monsterObj)
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(monster => console.log(monster))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

    })
}
```

Comment: The only way when a page can behave like you've described, is that theres a syntax error (or a runtime error is triggered before `event.preventDefault` is called) in `monsterSubmit` function, when it's not executed at all. It looks like your code doesn't contain syntax errors, though.

Comment: `monsterSubmit` when is execute?

Comment: is the form generated dynamically?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I edited the post showing the entire JS file.

Comment: @TheKNVB It is not.

Comment: I [can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/escg9wk6/) your issue. The alternatives are on my first comment, or you're running a cached script which is not the same as the example code in the post.

Comment: Your code is ok, please try to look console in network tab if ther's some error.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is not generated dynamically, I give you an example for your reference.

```js
function go(e,v){
    e.preventDefault();
  console.log(v.qq.value)
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="go(event,this)">
  <input name="qq" type="text">
</form>
```

In this example, you can type something in the text box, and then press enter, the page does not refresh and the entered value will be shown in console.